# Windows Media Services 2008 Programming

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-media-server

I'm looking in to Windows Media Services 2008 development. I've been able to set it up and create a publish point using Server Manager in Win 2008. But what I really want to do is to do this programatically.

I'm currently downloading windows 2008 SDK since it should have support for media services programming. What I want to know is
- Whether any of you had done this before?
- What are the challenges I should expect?
- Will the SDK have manged code for media services?

Thanks All!

Uchitha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to part 3 of my question on managed code.

Yes WindowsSDK does provide a Com wrapper (Primary Interop Assembly) to Window Media Services. The parent object of the wrapper is 'WMSServerObject'. The SDK documentation provides enough material to get me going.

Here's the Windows SDK help link.

'ms-help://MS.MSSDK.1033/MS.WinSDK.1033/wmsrvsdk/htm/sdkarchitecture.htm'

Comment: Uchitha - Do you know the web link?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You can try the following MSDN link though. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd875246(v=vs.85).aspx                             It's been a while since I worked on Windows Media Server, so not 100% sure.

Comment: @Uchitha did you find a way to develop locally, as oppsed to having to develop on a windows 2008 server instance ?

Comment: @guiomie I'm sorry I did a media server project 4 years ago and my memory could be hazy. However it's no different to any other COM related development. I guess you add the COM wrapper as a reference. The link I've provided in the previous comment instructs you on how to create a local server object.